# Merging multiple SpatiaLite databases into a single one with ogrmerge.py

Tags: ogr, ogrmerge

I have a folder with multiple SpatiaLite databases. I'd like to use `ogrmerge.py` to merge them into a single database... But if I use the command:

```
ogrmerge.py -f SQLite -single -o output.sqlite *.sqlite
```

I receive the error:

```
    - 'VirtualXPath'    [XML Path Language - XPath]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ogrmerge.py", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/utils/ogrmerge.py", line 618, in main
    return process(argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/utils/ogrmerge.py", line 456, in process
    writer.open_element('OGRVRTLayer',
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/utils/ogrmerge.py", line 168, in open_element
    xml_attrs = xml_attrs + ' %s=\"%s\"' % (key, _Esc(attrs[key].encode('utf-8')))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 12-13: surrogates not allowed
```

What am I missing? When I try merging the same files as Shapefiles with `ogrmerge.py -f "ESRI Shapefile" -single *.shp -o output.shp` it works fine. How can I merge SpatiaLite files with `ogrmerge.py`?

Comment: Which version of GDAL/OGR and OS are you using? This sounds like a character encoding issue (non utf-8). Try to find out the exact encoding used for creating these data and replace `xml_attrs = xml_attrs + ' %s=\"%s\"' % (key, _Esc(attrs[key].encode('utf-8')))`  If you cannot find out the exact encoding, try some common ones, e.g., `windows-1252`

Comment: @PDash I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with the GDAL 3.0.4... Actually, I'm not completely sure if `ogrmergy.py` can merge input files that are not Shapefiles since the examples that I find are always using Shapefiles as input (https://gdal.org/programs/ogrmerge.html). My Spatialite files look ok when I open them with QGIS. I'd like to find a solution that doesn't require me to change the `ogrmerge.py` source code.

Comment: Did you try setting a different encode spec? any change?

On your `sqlite db` Q, valid thought but I think it will; may need additional geopackages, e.g. `sqlite spatialite` & additional `keys` in your script.

Also, look at:
`https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195160/merge-natural-earth-sqlite-country-polygons-using-ogr2ogr-and-st-union`

Installing a complete Sys on Linux was painful. Here are some packages u will need:
`https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/libspatialite-sources/libspatialite-$spatialite_version.tar.gz`
`https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3320300.tar.gz`